# Filter an ArrayIngerField using Django

Tags: arrays, django, python-2.7

I am new to Django and i need to make a filter comparing arrays of integers.

I have:

```
class MyClass(Model):
   array_int = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

So I need to do something like

```
# array_int is [5,0,0,0]
MyClass.objects.filter(array_int<'{6,0,0,0}')
```

How to make this comparison in django?

Comment: What are you trying to compare? The sum of the elements of the array? The first element?

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade, i store in array number of versions and now i need to compare those numbers. Example: 5.0.0.0 < 6.0.0.0.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(array_int__lt=[6, 0, 0, 0])
```